# After I leave my computer on for several hours it stops opening applications

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I just started running into this about a month ago.  Basically when I boot my machine everything runs fine, but if I walk away and come back a few hours later I can no longer start new processes.  This includes:

- FireFox
- IE
- Visual Studio
- Task Manager
- Rebooting or shutting down the machine

I can still move around in open programs, but starting anything new does not work.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen?  I've done a virus scan and nothing comes up.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: open task manager before it happens, go away come back, and see if you spot anything in task manager. try  removing processes until you find the culprit and can suddenly open processes again. that's an approach that'll help to solve it.. report back

Comment: @barlop: That should be posted as an answer.  For such an edge case like the OP's situation, this is the best course of action.

Comment: sort-of sounds like one of the programs (on the list or not) is "leaking memory", or better to say "wasting resources" somehow due to poor programming or unexpected usage, or unexpected total system. Meaning it is not always poor programming, but unexpected operations or continual fails occuring, because the system is different. Must test by closing each program one at a time and seeing if it was related to the problem. Including the less seen background processes. I have seen leakers, and still use one, also some system "changes" cause program fails which incur "leakage".

Comment: @surfasb but it's not quite an answer,it's a possible approach to solving it,and the approach may not work out.The approach may actually lead the questioner to finding exactly what the problem is and then they or I could answer it,and if they're doing lots of diagnosing themselves then they could best answer it.Whatever it is, a diagnostic approach is the way my comment was,and they'd have to report back.It is likely that my method will work.in which case I or they could post it as an answer.I could post it as an answer I spose.and they do seem a bit slow in reporting back.they were on 1h ago

Comment: They receive a notification either way.

Comment: @[Psycogeek](http://superuser.com/users/98855/psycogeek) usually a 'leaking' program will cause crashes and a significant overall slowdown of system resources. The OP has not mentioned any crashes, just the inability to open any new processes?

Answer (score 1):

open task manager before it happens, go away come back, and see if you spot anything in task manager. try removing processes until you find the culprit and can suddenly open processes again. that's an approach that'll help to solve it.. report back

You can of course order processes my how much RAM they take up.. or CPU Usage. These could lead you to a culprit process.

Comment: I implemented some of Haydn's changes and have the task manager up and running.  Will report back tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @AbeMiessler you could try to time how long it takes to go funny. See if it's the same length every time.  From there, a few ideas are I suppose you could google the length of time it takes, or check event viewer perhaps.  Also if you're not at that computer, then you could use logmein to have a look to see if it has gone funny and if a particular fix works on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your power settings, verify (or change) the option to put your Hard Drive to sleep to see if that fixes the issue. Other things to check would be suspend options, pci and usb low-power options (personally i turn these all off)

Comment: The hard drive was set to sleep after 20 minutes.  Should I set it to not sleep?

Comment: @AbeMiessler  A good question is has Haydn ever seen  hard drive sleeping as a cause for what you are experiencing..or is it a wild guess on his part.   That aside..  if haydn's theory is right, then actually you could set it to sleep after a small amount of minutes, and see if you run into the problem.. (-then put it back-)  It's called troubleshooting.  I suppose he means for the "other things" like low power usb, he turns off their suspend modes, but you have no mouse issue for example.

Comment: @[Abe Miessler](http://superuser.com/users/33440/abe-miessler) Change the setting and see if it makes a difference.
@[barlop](http://superuser.com/users/42672/barlop) I have seen drives sleeping causing programs to crash, mostly on older machines/drives where the spinup time was quite substantial :)